# Optimizing copying one array to another with some offset

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code where I used two for loops to iterate through and array and copy elements to another at an offset position, how could this be done without for loops for faster computation?

```
for i in range (data1.shape[0]):
    for j in range (data1.shape[1]):
        try:
            translated[i+x_cord][j+y_cord]=data1[i][j]

        except:
            pass
```

Here, I'm just doing image translation.

Comment: Yes, use slices.

Comment: Do you know how to index (with slices) the target zone in `translated`?  Why does  your loop code use a `try/except`?  Do you expect that some of the assignments will not work?  will be out of bounds?  Can you tell us the `shape` of `translated`, and it relates to the shape of `data1` and the offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
translated[x_cord:min(x_cord+data1.shape[0],translated.shape[0]), y_cord:min(y_cord+data1.shape[1],translated.shape[1])] = data1[:min(data1.shape[0],translated.shape[0]-x_cord), :min(data1.shape[1],translated.shape[1]-y_cord)]
```

The `min` stuff is to ensure you are not going out of bounds (analog of your `try`, `except`), the rest is basic slicing...

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1038,1235) into shape (0,1235), I get the above error

Comment: That means your translation is completely out of bounds, just add more checks...